# Change 5th number from list

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a one function for my calendar

```py
def formatweek(self, theweek, events):
    week = ''
    for d, weekday in theweek:

        #return f'<tr style="color:blue";> {week} </tr>'
        week += self.formatday(d, events)
    return f'<tr> {week} </tr>'

def formatday(self, day, events):
    events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day=day)
    d = ''
    for event in events_per_day:
        d += f'<li> {event.get_html_url} </li>'

    if day != 0:
        return f"<td><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul> {d} </ul></td>"
    return '<td></td>'
```

where `theweek` is a list of pairs:

```
 [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6)]
 [(8, 0), (9, 1), (10, 2), (11, 3), (12, 4), (13, 5), (14, 6)]
 [(15, 0), (16, 1), (17, 2), (18, 3), (19, 4), (20, 5), (21, 6)]
 [(22, 0), (23, 1), (24, 2), (25, 3), (26, 4), (27, 5), (28, 6)]
 [(29, 0), (30, 1), (31, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6)]
```

Where the first number(for example(1)) in pairs is day in month (1.januar) and the second is a number for weekday name (0-Monday, 1-Thuesday etc...)

`d` and `weekday` become an `int` in loop. `d` = days of month (1,2,3,4....)and `Weekday` = number for days (Mon - 0, Tue - 1 etc...).
It returns this `return f'<tr> {week} </tr>'`for the table. And I would like to make it return for 5th and 6th weekday numbers (Saturday, Sunday) additionally  `f'<tr style="color:blue";> {5 (or 6)} </tr>'`.

So the simple say: **I would like to make a weekend days to become blue.**

Comment: We still don't know what `events` are like. If they are irrelevant to the problem itself, then create a minimal reproducible example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: events are just a objects like this:Event object (1)
Event object (2)

Comment: <class 'cal.models.Event'>

Comment: they are an events in that day in calendar

Comment: What is stopping you from doing `if day == 5 or day == 6`? Also you could do this in a template with for loop counter check, also you could do this in pure css with n-th child filter.

Comment: @Ivan Starostin I was doing if day == 5 then do `color`, but when I used it, all number became blue, because I dont know how to use it only for the 5th...